# Перезапуск программы на питон

Tags: python, selenium, ос

У меня есть программа на питоне которая запускает ~30 браузеров, спустя несколько часов работы обычно в каком-то браузере происходит непредвиденная ошибка, однако по логике моего приложения все 30 браузеров должны работать одновременно, так как моя программа крашится, я попробовал обернуть main() в try:, finally: блок и перезапускать ее через os.system("main.py"), однако тут всплыл подводный камень. В таком случае моя программа не заканчивает работу окончательно, и вместо того чтобы перезапустить 30 браузеров, оно откроет еще 30 вместе с оставшимися 29. Я пришел к выводу что мне нужно написать вторую программу которая будет следить за процессом main.py раз в минуту, и если он неактивен - перезапускать его. Заранее спасибо!

Comment: А в чем вопрос?

Comment: почему бы вам не запускать каждый браузер в отдельном процессе, а в случае краша закрывать процесс и открывать новый?

Comment: Вопрос в том что когда программа main.py крашится, а крашится она когда 1 из браузеров вылетает, мне нужно перезапустить все 30 браузеров, я не знаю как мне это сделать, если просто перезапустить программу откроется еще 30 браузеров и их получится в сумме 59

Comment: вы имеете ввиду использовать библиотеку multiprocessing? Я просто не разбираюсь в таких вещах :(

Comment: Научите свою программу не падать при падении браузера(браузеров) а аккуратно их закрывать а потом снова открывать.

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понял, проблема в том, чтобы закрыть все браузеры сразу.

Можно завершать все процессы хрома в функции перезапуска

```
TARGET = "chrome.exe"
[process.kill() for process in psutil.process_iter() if process.name() == TARGET]
```

Comment: Спасибо! Вот это как одно из решений без контроля краша программы - отлично подходит